# How can I completely remove TFS from VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I've tried out the online version of TFS from my MSDN subscription and didn't like it. I decided to use another provider of source control on the web.

Now I keep randomly getting the TFS explorer window popping up on loading solutions and error TF205020 about not being able to connect to TFS. I've gone into Tools, Options and removed the source control options, setting it to "None" (I'm using TortoiseSVN from Windows Explorer for check-ins).

When I create a new project, save it and open it again I get the error and the TFS windows, even after closing them. I've looked at the File menu to see if I can remove from  source control but the menu option isn't there - presumably because the new project has not been checked in.

Any way to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't remove your TFS server from VS servers list.

Go to `Team->Connect to Team Foundation Server...->Connect->Servers...` and remove your server from there.

Comment: I don't seem to have that option. When I click Connect to Team Foundation Server I get the web site stuff. I can go through this by adding my details but it's as if I'm not signed up. Once through the step, there's no option to remove anything.

Comment: So maybe try to open View->Team Explorer->Connect (screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/sNWTzEm.png)

Comment: And what is happening when you click Connect?

Comment: I get the "Connect to Team Foundation Server" dialog box. No options in the drop-down, no collections and no projects listed. I've uploaded a screenshot at http://imageshack.us/a/img69/2391/hg1f.png.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Source Control`

Change Current source control plug-in to None

You can now remove the TFS server.